# Loop through a Json Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

This is the JSON format returned from Postman:

```
e[{
"OrderID": 10248,
"CustomerID": "VINET",
"ContactName": "Paul Henriot",
"EmployeeID": 5,
"OrderDate": "/Date(836431200000)/",
"RequiredDate": "/Date(838850400000)/",
"ShippedDate": "/Date(837468000000)/",
"ShipVia": 3,
"Freight": 32.38,
"ShipName": "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
"ShipAddress": "59 rue de l'Abbaye",
"ShipCity": "Reims",
"ShipRegion": null,
"ShipPostalCode": "51100",
"ShipCountry": "France",
"ProductID": 11,
"ProductName": "Queso Cabrales",
"UnitPrice": 14,
"Quantity": 12,
"Discount": 0},
{
    "OrderID": 10248,
    "CustomerID": "VINET",
    "ContactName": "Paul Henriot",
    "EmployeeID": 5,................
```

How to get iterate this array using a Javascript loop, so that for every ORDER ID it should display Product IDs, Product Names, Unit Prices, Discount? I have tried this:

```
e  function format(d)
{
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/Test/GetData", function (jsonResult)
    {
        ParseJson(jsonResult);
    })

    function ParseJson(response)
    {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            var id = response[i].OrderID;

            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + response[i].ProductID + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + response[i].ProductName + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + response[i].UnitPrice + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + response[i].Quantity + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + response[i].Discount + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        $(document).find("#entrydata").html(html);
    }
    return '<table id = "entrydata" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
  '</table>';
}
```

But this code returns all product details in the database, for every Order ID.

Comment: From what I can tell, this has absolutely nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSON.parse() to get JS array from this json and then iterate on it with normal JS loop. While it's an array, you can use `.forEach`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example

If you want to cycle through object, then you can use
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

to get array of keys and then use `.forEach` on keys array

Comment: I am trying something like this in the beginning :

function format(d)
    {


        var x = $.getJSON("/Test/GetData");


        var y = JSON.parse(x);


But doesnt work

Comment: haven't used jQuery for the last 3 years, can't tell what's wrong, but i'm using `JSON.parse` all the time and it works really well.